Coloring four to five dots in a circle in m colors
Problem: $n$ dots arranged in a circle are to be painted in $m$ (where $m≥3$) colours in such fashion that no adjacent dots are of same color. Besides, we are not obliged to use every color.
There is a recurrence relation for this problem:
$N_{n} = (m-2)N_{n-1} + (m-1)N_{n-2}.$
However, it is only valid for $n≥4$. Does it mean that initial conditions ($n=4, n=5$) are to be counted manually?
If so, I must admit that I have encountered some problems with basic combinatorics here.
$n=4: 
N_{4} = m(m-1)(m-2)(m-3)+2m^2(m-1)$
The first term is intended to count scenarios where all colors are different, while the second term accounts for scenarios where either the second dot matches the last one or the one before the last matches the first one. Yet I suspect this is not entirely correct. Where might I have gone wrong?

Let us consider one of the points. A way to colour the points is to fix the colour of that fixed point (so $m-2$ ways, since the colour has to be different from the colour of the adjacent points) and for each colour chosen we have $N_{n-1}$ possibilities to count the remain $n-1$ points.
However there are other configurations not yet considered to colour the points, indeed it can happen that the adjacent points of that fixed point have the same colour.
In this case, every time we fix the colour of the adjacent points (so $m-1$ ways, since we have to exclude the colour of the specific point) we have $N_{n-2}$ ways to colour the remain points (we are considering the other points together with the fixed point and one of the adjacent points as the $n-2$ points).
This gives the recurrence relation $N_n=(m-2)N_{n-1}+(m-1)N_{n-2}$.
I don't see why this does not work for $n=4$. Instead, it does not work for $n=3$, and the right formula is $N_3=m(m-1)(m-2)$. The formula for $n=4$ is then
$$N_4=(m-2)N_3+(m-1)N_2=m(m-1)(m-2)^2+m(m-1)^2=m(m-1)((m-2)^2+m-1)=m(m-1)(m^2-3m+3)$$

Ah, I see it now! I erroneously assumed that terms like $N_{3}$ (even if calculated analytically) are inherently incorrect for a relation relevant for $n≥4$. Much thanks for clearing up my confusion!

You could use the recurrence
$$N_n=m(m-1)^{n-1}-N_{n-1}$$
which is valid for $n\ge4$. (Hint: $m(m-1)^{n-1}$ is the answer to the analogous question for points arranged in a straight line.) So
$$N_4=m(m-1)^3-m(m-1)(m-2)=m(m-1)(m^2-3m+3).$$
By induction on $n$ you can prove that
$$N_n=m(m-1)^{n-1}-m(m-1)^{n-2}+m(m-1)^{n-3}-\cdots+(-1)^nm(m-1).$$
The sum of this geometric progression is
$$N_n=(m-1)^n+(-1)^n(m-1).$$
In particular
$$N_5=(m-1)^5-(m-1)=m(m-1)(m-2)(m^2-2m+2).$$
